# FeedItem Trigger - Parse Mentions?

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter, feeditem, mentions

There are many questions out the about how to add `@mentions` to a chatter post, but this question is the other way around:

> How do I read `@mentions` from a `FeedItem` in the trigger context?

I need to be able to reliably get the Ids of any `User` record (and maybe `Group` record in the future) which is `@mentioned`. The idea is that we want to use `Apex Sharing` to bridge the gap if someone gets `@mentioned` but doesn't yet have access to the record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I'd love to see someone else find a better way to do it, but I have discovered one working option: *serialization*. When looking at a serialized `FeedItem` in my debug logs, I saw something like:

> `..."RawBody": "<p>Sample text... {@005000000000000AAA}</p>"...`

However, I wasn't able to acceess this data via normal means. When I look at the `Body`, it would look like:

> `<p>Sample text... @FirstName LastName</p>`

Which is more of a pain to parse from an expression standpoint and also requires an additional query. Yuck. Anyway, here's a simple proof of concept how to get the `@mentions` from trigger `FeedItem` records:

```
public with sharing class FeedItemService
{
    public static final String USER_PREFIX = SObjectType.User.getKeyPrefix();
    public static final String EXPRESSION = '\\{@(' + USER_PREFIX +'[0-9a-zA-Z]{15})\\}';
    public static Pattern RAW_MENTION = Pattern.compile(EXPRESSION);

    public static void parse(List<FeedItem> feedItems)
    {
        for (Mention mention : (List<Mention>)JSON.deserialize(
            JSON.serialize(feedItems), List<Mention>.class
        )){
            system.debug(mention);
            // or do something more interesting
        }
    }

    public class Mention
    {
        final String rawBody;
        final Id parentId;
        Set<Id> getUserIds()
        {
            Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
            Matcher m = RAW_MENTION.matcher(rawBody);
            while (m.find()) userIds.add(m.group(1));
            return userIds;
        }
    }
}
```

I do some additional filtering before parsing any records to at least make sure the `Body` field contains an `@` character, since serialization tends to be an expensive process.

Comment: I'm really impressed that you noticed that the `RawBody` is serialized and can be used to extract the mentioned IDs. One enhancement you could make is to also parse `CollaborationGroup` IDs, since Chatter groups can also be mentioned. I'm going to post an alternate solution, but I suspect that yours is more performant.

Comment: Doesn't look like `rawBody` is supported anymore. After deserializing, `rawBody` is null.

Comment: That's a bummer.

Answer (score 10):

I suspect that Adrian's solution is the more performant one, but here's a solution that doesn't use the undocumented rawBody serialization trick. It uses the `ConnectApi` Apex namespace, because @mentions in Chatter are only supported in `ConnectApi` or the Chatter REST API.

In your `FeedItem` trigger, re-fetch the feed items using `ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementBatch` and then inspect the `ConnectApi.FeedBody` as shown in [ConnectApiHelper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper/blob/master/ConnectApiHelper.cls#L275):

```
trigger MyTrigger on FeedItem (after insert) {
    String communityId = Network.getNetworkId();
    List<String> feedItemIds = new List<String>();
    for (FeedItem f : trigger.new) {
        feedItemIds.add(f.id);
    }

    // Re-fetch the feed items passed into the trigger
    ConnectApi.BatchResult[] results = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementBatch(communityId, feedItemIds);

    for (ConnectApi.BatchResult result : results) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Object theResult = result.getResult();
            if (theResult instanceof ConnectApi.FeedItem) {
                ConnectApi.FeedItem item = (ConnectApi.FeedItem) theResult;

                for (ConnectApi.MessageSegment segment : item.body.messageSegments) {
                    if (segment instanceof ConnectApi.MentionSegment) {
                        ConnectApi.MentionSegment theMention = (ConnectApi.MentionSegment) segment;
                        String mentionedId = theMention.record.id;
                        // Do what you need to do with mentionedId...
                        System.debug('Mentioned ID: ' + mentionedId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```